# Getting ID from previous page to field on next page (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session

Basically all I want  to do is from my view page which is displaying a specific article then having a delete link to a page with a field and a button for deleting that article with the id displayed in that field.

I have had a go at this for the last couple of days trying to put the id in the URL link i.e "delete?id=20" and trying to access it with a $_GET and then I tried "delete/20" and URI segments. 
Then I attempted at using sessions etc but i am not sure which is best as I haven't got any of them working.

I have decided to show my untouched code and start from scratch here is my code:

**view.php**

```
<?php 
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo '<p>'.$news_item['text'].'</p>'; 
?><br><br>

<a href="http://website.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/news">
Go to latest news</a>

<a href = "http://website.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/delete">Delete</a><br>
```

**delete.php**

```
<h2>Delete a news item</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('news/delete') ?>

<form>
<label for="delete">Article Number</label><br> 
<input name="id" class="resizedTitlebox" value="id" /><br>      
<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete news item" /></form>
```

**news.php (controller)**

```
 <?php

 class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
}


public function view($slug)

    {

$data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

   if (empty($data['news_item']))
   {
    show_404();
   }

$data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/view', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }


    public function delete() {
    {   
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $data['title'] = 'Delete news item';

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('id',  'required');


      if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
      {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
                $this->load->view('news/delete');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

      }
      else
      {
            $data['id'] = $this->news_model->delete('id');
            $this->load->view('news/success');
              }
             }
         }
```

**news_model.php (model)**

```
    <?php

    class News_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()   {

    $this->load->database();
}


   public function get_news($slug = FALSE){

     $this->load->helper('text');

 if ($slug === FALSE){
     $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
     return $query->result_array();
 }

 $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
 return $query->row_array();
     } 



     public function set_news(){

     $this->load->helper('url');

     $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

     $data = array(
         'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
          'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
          'slug' => $slug,
          'text' => $this->input->post('text'));

      return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
        }


    public function delete ($id)  {

          $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('id'));
          $this->db->delete('news');
      }
     }
```

**routes.php (config)**

```
    $route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
    $route['news/delete'] = 'news/delete';
    $route['news'] = 'news';
    $route['default_controller'] = 'news';
    $route['404_override'] = '';
```

### Thanks in advance for any help given!

@jeroen answer

"You are not passing any value in the delete link; you should add an ID either to the path or the query string" - I assume you mean like

```
  <a href = "http://website.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/delete?article_id=<?php echo $news_item['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

So using article_id. Then I can define article_id in the delete controller? I am not sure how this can be done.

answer:
        $this->input->get(article_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete procedure seems strange and has some errors:

1. You are no specifying a method in your form, so that will default to `GET` but in your delete function you use `$this->input->post('id')`. You should change your form to `<form action="" method="POST">`;
2. You are sending a variable to your delete function that you don't use: `$id`. This is a string in your controller although the name in the model seems to suggest an ID. But you are not using it anyway...
3. You are expecting a return value from the delete function when you call it in your controller but you don't return anything from your function.
4. You are not passing any value in the delete link; you should add an ID either to the path or the query string, but be careful not to use the same name `$id` if you use the same controller as the form will validate without the confirmation;
5. You are not getting any value for the ID in the `delete` controller and passing it to the view to fill the value of your ID field.

By the way, there is no input type `id` but that should not cause any problems as it defaults to `text`.

Comment: I am not sure if I have made my self clear as the form itself succesfully deletes an item from the dtabase with a manually entered id.

However, I do agree with some things that are in there unnecerssarily and I have changed the aspects you mentioned. For the          <form action="" method="POST">;
I have tried this previously when trying to GET the id from the url delete?id=20. But to know avail, I am certain that I changed the config.

I apologise in advance if I am not making much sense have only come into PHP/CodeIgniter past couple of weeks.

Comment: @Purgatory Okay, added some additional things in my answer.

Comment: @Purgatory The variable should be available in the controller as `$this->input->get(article_id)` if the routing does not interfere with the query string (haven't used CodeIgniter in a while...).

Comment: Thanks I managed to get it working using your assistance and even managed to take that and use it on an edit page thank you very much for your assistance. I will mark as answered however, I have a image based vertical navigation bar that for ease I have pasted on all of my view pages however I was wandering if it possible to use it in a codeigniter, I am aware that it can be done with a text based navigation but with a image based navigation? If you are not sure don't worry, thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think their is no need of delete view page.You can directly delete news item from your news list page

```
<a href = "http://website.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/delete">Delete</a><br>
```

instead of this line use this

```
<a href = "<?php echo site_url("news/delete/".$news_item['id']); ?>Delete</a>
```

And in your controller

```
public function delete($id){
    $this->news_model->delete($id);
    $this->load->view('news/success');
  }
```

And in your model use this

```
function Delete($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        if($this->db->delete("news"))
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was originally just creating a basic CRUD website and was next going to look for a way to do this after I will test and get back to you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: So I gave it a go and `<a href = "<?php echo site_url("news/delete/".$news_item['id']); ?>">Delete</a> ` doesnt show a delete link on the page? Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: I changed it to the following `<a href = "<?php echo ("news/delete/".$news_item['id']); ?>">Delete</a>` and the link appears however it gets a 404 because it doesnt recognise delete/67....isnt this getting into URI segments which I couldn't get working previously. Thanks.

Comment: if site_url wont work then you have to use ful link:
<a href = "http://website.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/news/delete/"<?php echo $news_item['id'] ?>>Delete</a><br>

Comment: I know this was a while ago but I tried this again and it still produces a 404 because it doesnt recognise delete/id as a page if you have any further adjustments you could recommend I would be most grateful. Thanks.